# Integrating legacy Application with Salesforce

Tags: integration

We are on planning on integrating our legacy application with Salesforce.

We have not yet decided on approaches and methodologies.

As a starting point we are meeting with the architect of the legacy application.

To be able to start planning for the integration project, What questions should I ask the Architect?

Comment: please specify more details on business logic of the app. also what are the participants of these project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally following points should be touched:

- Outline high-level requirements: what is integration goal. what is your
  expectation for the result of collaboration of these systems. Try to draw some vision of the integration. This will be major driver for whole integration project and approaches taken.
- Authorization and security
- Checkout connection details (if app is available from external
  endpoints. if it supports HTTP and etc) and APIs available on both sides
- If it is (near) real-time integration or scheduled jobs to sync data
- What changes could be done to legacy system
- If you can embed UI of legacy app to Salesforce
- Is it direct integration or will be done via middle-ware such as MuleSoft or Dell Boomy
- If it is Legacy system - what is transition process

Most important aspect here is data flows:

- Data flows from one system to another.
- Entity and field mappings
- which system masters which data.
- Data updates policy - which app can update? what fields can update? when can update?